# Как в Visual studio code подключить модули?

Tags: python

Я хотела установить модуль colorama и вписала в терминал pip install colorama
Но он показал мне ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас добавлен питон в PATH?

Comment: При установке Пайтоне я ставила галочку на PATH

Comment: Тогда странно... Вы после установки перезагружали пк?

Comment: Да (не обращайте внимание на это, просто нужно чтобы было много слов, так как меня Стэк не допускает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Запустите установку через cmd. Там будет видно есть ошибки ли нет. IDE не всегда надежны в этом вопросе. И проверьте если ли pip `pip -V`
2. Если pip нет и в консоли то лучше всего переустановите Python (просто так проще)
3. Установить pip вручную. Скачиваем [get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) и устанавливаем `python get-pip.py`

Answer (score 0):

Показал на скрине, Параметры/Расширения
https://prnt.sc/wl69uu
https://prnt.sc/wl6a4r

Comment: Боюсь что в данном случае нужна библиотека python а они через маркетплейс VSC не ставятся.